# What's this part and why its color is rusty? The laptop also make car engine on the highway sound

Tags: laptop, motherboard

Do I need to change this part or the fan?
[image: inside the laptop]

Answer (score 2):

The marked areas are designating a device known as a heat pipe. It transfers the heat from the processor it covers to the fins that are cooled by airflow from the fan. It is copper and you are not seeing rust. As copper oxidizes, it acquires a patina that it harmless, unless the oxidation is caused by a liquid that should have be inside a laptop computer!

The noise question is ambiguous. Without additional detail, only guesses are valid. The guess in this case would be that the fan bearings are worn. As you are able to progress to this point in disassembly, you should be able to locate a replacement fan and replace the fan.

Use your preferred internet search engine with the terms "replacement fan [your model computer]" in order to locate a suitable product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
The fan make a constant abnormal sound and almost daily it can make a sudden loud sound that's exactly like a car engine speeding up the highway. How do I know the type and size of the fan to get in order to replace it with this one?

Comment: note my addition to the answer.

Comment: or put a bit of sewing machine oil on the fan axle

Comment: Extremely light weight oil may serve to quiet the fan, but it will also collect dust and eventually cause a complete fan failure. The noise is very likely excessive wear on the bearings, requiring a replacement for a proper solution.

Comment: Never lubricate dry bearings. You will be able to find a complete new fan assembly on such as Ali Express or eBay. Just use the part number on the sticker rather than the computer model.

Comment: thank you @fred_dot_u for your additional comments

Comment: thank you @Tetsujin for your answer, which sticker are you referring to?

Comment: Just keep stripping it until you find natural break-points. See what numbers you can match up. You'll probably be able to get just the fan housing… number will be underneath.